# Can apache use the Alias directive to fetch a file?

Tags: apache-2.2, alias

I was wondering if there is a way to use the Alias directive with just one file. Or there was a hack to do this, without having to go into another directory.

Answer (score 26):

Yes you can - the [config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) for the `Alias` directive says:

`Syntax:    Alias URL-path file-path|directory-path`

So you can have a directive such as:

`Alias /robots.txt /path/to/robots.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You could use mod_rewrite. Here is a good tutorial explaining how it works and how to use it:

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting

Comment: No need for mod_rewrite, where simple Alias will do.